# VB.net How to Calculate the 15th and 30th of the month?

Tags: vb.net

For example, the 15th of January is from Jan 1 to 15, and the 30th of January is Jan 1 to Jan 30. Since not all months are composed of 30 days, therefore the 15th of February will be from Jan 31 to February 14. So what could be the formula in getting the 15th and 30th of the PRESENT month? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if its not a leap year, 15th of March would be 17th March??? This question is messing with my brain

Comment: You want to split the year into 15-day intervals? What would you do with leap years? Or just divide months into two parts of 15, even if there's some overlap/shortage? When you say "how to calculate" I'm not convinced you've decided on what you want yet, because that would probably already be a good description of how to calculate it?

Comment: do you want to calculate the day number of the year or the day of the week?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the number for which day of the year it is? If so you can do this

```
Sub Main()
    Dim FIFTEENTH As DateTime = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, 15)
    Dim THIRTIETH As DateTime
    Dim hasThirty As Boolean = (DateTime.DaysInMonth(Now.Year, Now.Month) >= 30)

    Console.WriteLine("The fifteenth: ")
    Console.WriteLine($"Day of the Year: {FIFTEENTH.DayOfYear}")
    Console.WriteLine($"Day of the Week: {FIFTEENTH.DayOfWeek.ToString("D")} / {FIFTEENTH.DayOfWeek.ToString("g")}")

    If (hasThirty) Then
        Console.WriteLine("The Thirtieth: ")

        Console.WriteLine($"Day of the Year: {THIRTIETH.DayOfYear}")
        Console.WriteLine($"Day of the Week: {THIRTIETH.DayOfWeek.ToString("D")} / {THIRTIETH.DayOfWeek.ToString("g")}")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Using a `Try Catch` to determine if a month has 30 days seems a bit of an overkill!  Why not just `hasThirty = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Now.Year, Now.Month) >= 30` ??  `Try Catch` can be expensive performance wise.